# Intellij IDEA import checkstyle scheme doesn't work properly

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea, checkstyle

I am currently configuring checkstyle for my Intellij IDEA and found out that when I import checkstyle config for my code style (Editor/Code Style/Import Scheme/CheckStyle Configuration) the config that gets imported is different from the one in checkstyle.

For instance, 
In checkstyle.xml I have:

```
    <module name="ImportOrder">
        <property name="groups" value="/^javax?\./,org,com" />
        <property name="ordered" value="true" />
        <property name="caseSensitive" value="true" />
        <property name="separated" value="true" />
        <property name="option" value="bottom" />
    </module>
```

I have separation between lines. However, Intellij IDEA config after import:

```
  <option name="IMPORT_LAYOUT_TABLE">
      <value>
        <package name="javax" withSubpackages="true" static="false" />
        <package name="java" withSubpackages="true" static="false" />
        <package name="org" withSubpackages="true" static="false" />
        <package name="" withSubpackages="true" static="true" />
        <package name="" withSubpackages="true" static="false" />
      </value>
    </option>
```

Such things break checkstyle when auto formating is applied. Similar differences are applicable to many other settings. Is there a better way to import checkstyle config? This one seems buggy.

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, isn't it plugin related issue? I mean without the plugin "Editor/Code Style/Import Scheme/CheckStyle Configuration" isn't even showing as an option.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-219808?project=IDEA